# how to set the field in sqlite db?

Tags: sqlite

```
C:\Users\root>sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> create table data(code TEXT,amount real);
sqlite> insert into data (code,amount) values('x1',17.8937465);
sqlite> insert into data (code,amount) values('x1',177777777777.8937465);
sqlite> select * from data;
x1|17.8937465
x1|177777777777.894
```

How can i set field to get when `select * from data;`

```
x1|17.8937
x1|177777777777.8937
```

that is to say ,no matter how long the integer part is ,the whole integer part will be displayed ,
100 digits in integer part or 1 digit in integer part,
all of them will be displayed,but only 4 digits in decimal part will be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select code, round(amount, 4)
from data
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d41d8/1271)

Comment: can i keep 4 digits when inserting the record ?not round it when selecting?

Comment: Yes, either insert the data using `round()` or use a data type like `decimal(15,4)` that has only 4 decimal places to store it.

Comment: if there is  a large number which has 30 digits in integer part?

Comment: Then use a data type like `decimal(40,4)`

Comment: it is unluky that i don't know how big the number will be in advance.